# How to integrate this by substitution: $∫ [2π(4-x)2\sqrt{1 - (x-1)^2}]dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How would I integrate this from 0 to 2 using substitution?  $$∫ [2π(4-x)2\sqrt{1 - (x-1)^2}]dx$$

Comment: whats that $2$ between the $(4-x)$ and $\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}$?

Comment: It's just multiplied with everything inside the integral

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let:

$$\text{u}=x-1\tag1$$

And after that, let:

$$\text{u}=\sin\left(\text{s}\right)\tag2$$

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate further?

Answer (score 0):

With $x-1=\sin u$ we have

$$I=4\pi\int (3-\sin u)\cos^2u\ du$$

$$=12\pi\int \cos^2u\ du-4\pi\int \sin u \cos^2u \ du$$

$$=12\pi\int \frac12(1+\cos(2u))\ du-4\pi\left(-\frac{\cos^3u}{3}\right)$$

$$=6\pi\left(u+\frac12\sin(2u)\right)+\frac{4\pi}{3}\cos^3u$$